# How to Get files by code from Nikon camera through C# windows forms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mtp

I have Nikon camera (D5200). For some reason, i want to copy files from the memory card of my camera directly through USB cable using C# windows forms application. I searched a lot for an API but didn't find.  Is there a way to do that ? Thanks

Comment: what api? the card will appear as a drive, like any other drive, and you can scan that drive for files like you would scan for files on any OTHER drive.

Comment: No, it doesn't appear like any other drive. It appears as MTP device and cannot be read through C# code